# jQuery random count with no number repeat until end of loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, math, random, counter

I've been trying hard at this. A jQuery counter function that counts from `0` to `6` continuously in random but no repeat of a number until end of the loop i.e. until the count of the 7th digit in the array. Currently the following code works for me but the numbers repeat. Please help!

```
function beginTimer() {
    if ($('#timer').html().length == 0) {
        timer(0) ;  
    }
}

function timer(i) {
    setTimeout("timer(" + (i) + ")", 1000);
    $('#timer').html(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
}
```

Comment: Generate the 7 random numbers without duplicates in to an array first, then loop through them. At end of the loop restart the process. The main problem now is that you're generating the random number on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to consider my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of the 7 digits, randomize the array by [shuffling the deck](http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array/) (do **not** use sort, despite what [fearless leader says](http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array/)), output them, then start again.  There's no way to avoid repeats without maintaining the list of numbers already output.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OldPro/4wrp5/)

```
var digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
digits.shuffle = function () {
    var i = this.length,
        j, temp;
    while (--i >= 0) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = this[i];
        this[i] = this[j];
        this[j] = temp;
    }
    this.lastOutput = -1;
};
digits.shuffle();

var output = function () {
    var i = ++digits.lastOutput;
    if (i >= digits.length) {
        digits.shuffle();
        i = 0;
    }

    $('#timer').html(digits[i]);
    this.lastOutput = i;
    setTimeout(output, 1000);
};

output();
```

Comment: Your initial code seems like what I'm quite looking for. I'm still working my way around it. If no luck I'll try your update likewise other responses to this thread. I'll keep you guys posted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you Old Pro for taking the time to write me a solution. It works quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of "digits" and pick from them until it no longer exists.

```
var digits = [];

// populate our digits array with 0-6
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    digits.push(i);

function timer() {
    // are there still digits remaining?
    if(!digits.length)
        return;

    // select a random digit and remove it from the array
    var digit = digits.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * digits.length ), 1 );

    $('#timer').html(digit);

    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqS9V/)**

Comment: Thank you Austin. Your code stops count when there's no digit left. I would like a continuous count.

Answer (score 0):

```
var counted = [];

function count() {
    var numb, go = true;

    while (go) {
        numb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        if (counted.indexOf(numb) == -1) counted.push(numb), go = false;
    }

    $('#timer').html(numb);
    if (counted.length > 5) counted = [];
    setTimeout(count, 300);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLeXV/)

Comment: You have done well Adeneo. Your response has been helpful and my problem solved. God bless you!